# Active Storage and Nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I've been looking everywhere for 3 hours and I couldn't find anything... not a single thing.

Here is my issue :

```
# User Model
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, class_name:"UserProfile", dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end

# UserProfile Model
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one_attached :avatar
end

# Form
<%= simple_form_for(current_user, :url => update_profile_settings_path, :method => :put) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :profile do |p| %>
    <%= p.input :avatar %>
    <%= p.input :firstname %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

# Controller
def update_profile_settings
  if current_user.update(user_params)
    redirect_to account_profile_settings_path, notice: 'Vos données ont bien été modifiées.'
  else
    render :profile_settings
  end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email, :avatar, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, profile_attributes: [:id, :firstname, :lastname, :bio, :birth_date, :avatar])
end
```

**Issue :**

For some reason, if I only try to upload an avatar, it won't work.

BUT if I try to upload an avatar and I update another field as well (let's say the firstname field, which is also a nested_attribute of User), then the avatar gets uploaded/updated.

Can anyone please help ?

I tried everything, couldn't find anything... It drives me crazy.

Comment: You need to change your avatar form field to `p.file_field :avatar`.

Comment: Nope. I'm usinge `simple_form` which automatically recognises the `:avatar` field to be an input file.